# Link validation with new image

Tags: javascript

Why does it give false domain as the result? Is there any better solution?

```
var domainlerimtek=["bock.com","sok.com","www.google.co.uk","coaskkdak.com"];
for(var i=0;i<domainlerimtek.length;i++)
{
var im = new Image();
im.src = document.location.protocol+"//"+domainlerimtek[i]+"/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
im.onload = function(){alert(im.src);};
}
```

or

```
var domainlerimtek=["bock.com","sok.com","www.google.co.uk","coaskkdak.com"];
for(var i=0;i<domainlerimtek.length;i++)
{
var im = new Image();var geci=i;
im.src = document.location.protocol+"//"+domainlerimtek[i]+"/images/srpr/logo3w.png";
im.onerror = function(){alert(geci);};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For some odd reason

```
    document.location.protocol
```

is searching for files locally

Answer (score 0):

I was only able to reproduce an error in Internet Explorer. To get it working there, I made two changes:

1. remove the last comma in your array declaration: var domainlerimtek=["bock.com","sok.com","www.google.co.uk","coaskkdak.com"**,**]; // <-- remove the last comma
2. change **document**.location.protocol to **window**.location.protocol